# Map json dynamically

Tags: java

I have a requirement to build a JSON dynamically and need to call an external API.
For instance,
Input : `"FIRST_NAME": "XXX"`
Based on the above input I need to build a JSON dynamically like below

```json
{
  "Req":{
    "user":{
      "CreatedTime":"2017-03-02T07:52:58Z",
      "UpdatedTime":"2017-03-02T07:52:58Z",
      "Details":{
        "Names":[
          {
            "Name":{
              "First":"kirtq"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I get contact number as input : `CONTACT_NUMBER:889999999`
Then I have to build a JSON like below

```json
{
  "UpdateMemberReq": {
    "Customer": {
      "CreatedTime": "2017-03-02T07:52:58Z",
      "UpdatedTime": "2017-03-02T07:52:58Z",
      "CustomerDetails": {
        "Contacts": {
          "MobilePhone": {
            "value": "07888728687"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Like this I have around 30 fields for each request I will get one filed based on that I have to build a JSON dynamically and once I prepared the JSON dynamically I have to call an external API (POST) by passing this JSON as raw type in the body.
I have implemented like below .

```
List list = new ArrayList();

        Name user = mapper.readValue(json2, Name.class);
        System.out.println(user);

        Map<String, Object> name1 = new HashMap<>();
        name1.put("Name", user);
        list.add(name1);

        Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("Names", list);

        Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("CustomerDetails",map1);

        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap();
        map.put("Customer",map2);
```

Can anyone suggest to me the best way to handle this in java/spring boot?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone suggest to me the best way to handle this in java/spring boot?

Given that you don't have a fixed schema for which you want to create JSON, you'll have to do exactly like you do.

This means assembling a map dynamically and then mapping it to a `json string`.

What you can do to improve is try to extract common and reusable components, for building certain parts of the request.

I'd recommend you create a class structure to keep things manageable with some classes like ...

1. `JsonGenerationService` ( the main service the rest of the code uses )
2. `UserJsonGenerator` -> generates JSON for user entities
3. `CustomerJsonGenerator` -> generates JSON for customers
4. `JsonGeneratorCommon` -> contains all the common methods

Comment: could you provide any reference to generate-UserJsonGenerator ,
CustomerJsonGenerator ,
JsonGeneratorCommon

Comment: These are custom classes which you must write. Each class will store code necessary to generate a specific type of JSON response